# Prevent `wget` hanging when it encounters error 500

Tags: command-line, wget

I am downloading a couple of thousand files listed in a file using:

```
wget -i filename
```

Sometimes it encounters the following error reported by the server for a particular file:

> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error

The problem is that `wget` then hangs. What I want for it to skip that file and continue downloading the rest of the list. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `wget --tries=1 --waitretry=1 -i filename`.  This will try only once after a failure and only wait one second before doing so.  It's also possible the server is not closing the socket after sending the 500 error.  In this case, adding `--read-timeout=30` will timeout the connection after 30 seconds of no data from the server.  See the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html)

Comment: `--tries=0` will retry indefinitely.  The server may be intentionally leaving the connection open - try setting `--read-timeout=15`

Comment: @JBentley On it